# English version of Afrikaans “gros”, meaning 144

Tags: single-word-requests

In Afrikaans we have the word gros, which means 12 dozen or 144. Usually that is how you buy eggs in large scale. Is there a English version of this word?

Comment: Did no Afrikaans-English dictionary help?

Answer (score 7):

The term ***[gross](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_(unit))*** is used in English:

> In English and related languages, several terms involving the words "great" or "gross" (possibly, from French: grosse thick) relate to numbers involving a multiple of exponents of twelve (dozen):
>
> ***A gross*** refers to a group of 144 items (a dozen dozen or a square dozen, 12<sup>2</sup>).
>
> ***A great gross*** refers to a group of 1728 items (a dozen gross or a cubic dozen, 12<sup>3</sup>).
>
> ***A small gross*** or a great hundred refers to a group of 120 items (ten dozen, 10×12).
>
> The continued use of these numbers in measurement and counting represents a continuation of the tradition of the [duodecimal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duodecimal) number system in everyday life and has encouraged groups such as [the Dozenal Society of America](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duodecimal#Advocacy_and_%22dozenalism%22) to advocate for a wider use of such a numbering system in place of decimal.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: I have only ever heard of the first of these.

Comment: @ColinFine same here, but learning of their existence does make the long ton and the short ton somewhat less vexing.  *Great gross* would be useful for puzzles or trivia concerning phrases comprising etymological doublets.

Comment: Did I ever tell you the 288 joke?  Well, I guess it's too gross.

Comment: I don't think _gross_ is used much now (in the UK, at least).  It may still be common in a few specific areas (which may include buying large numbers of eggs!), but I can't recall the last time I heard or used it, and many people probably wouldn't know it.  Similar applies to _score_ (20), though _dozen_ (12) is still fairly common.

Comment: "Gross" is still common in the US, especially in marketing.